# How to add remarks to SSAS cube using WRITEBACK?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas

**SQL 2014**

> Scenario: Finance department wants to review the data on SSAS cube and **add a comment where required**. Typical view is a parent-child hierarchy on the Y-Axis and Month on the X-Axis.

Preferred client is Excel but can use other client if it gets the job done.

I'm looking for a way to add comments to the cube, preferably as a measure. For example:

```
Parent1         JAN         FEB
    Child1      Comment 1   Comment 2
    Child1      Comment 3   Comment 4
```

I have successfully used writeback in the past but only in the standard way. I know there is a workaround worked with older versions of SQL (2005?) but I could not make it work with SQL 2014.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in Analysis Services feature that will achieve this. You could write your own VBA macros to automate saving comments to a database or purchase an Excel add-in called [Vivid](https://www.varigence.com/Vivid) which handles this scenario. They call the feature commentary.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I'll take a look. I'm going to keep this one open just in case someone has another solution.